# How to Install D-LINK 502T on a desktop

Tags: 12.04, wireless, router

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 and have been trying to install and configure D-LINK USB Router 502T. I tried following various posts available on internet but no luck. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [D-Link DSL-502T Manual](ftp://files.dlink.com.au/products/DSL-502T/REV_A/Manuals/v3.00/DSL-502T_Manual_v3.00.pdf)

More resurces and tehnical support at: http://www.dlink.com.au/tech/download/download.aspx?product=DSL-502T&revision=REV_A&filetype=Manuals .